# Can the fact $(\sin x)'=\cos x$ be proved not using the fact $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$?

Tags: proof-verification

Is it possible to prove
$$\left(\sin(x)\right)^\prime = \cos(x)$$
*without* using the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$?

If so, Please give me the proof of that case.

Comment: Please tell more about your question. Also, use the search functionality for "sin x/x".

Comment: I can't parse this question: is it asking whether we can prove $\;(\sin x)'=\cos x\;$ *without* using $\;\sin x/x\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1\;$...or **what** is it asking?\

Comment: DonAntonio Yes.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the *definition* of the derivative of sine at $0$ is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin h}{h}$, so you are asking "can you differentiate sine at an arbitrary point $x$ without knowing how to differentiate it at $0$?".  The answer is pretty clearly no.  The best you can hope for is to change the definition of sine and cosine so that the difficulty of the calculation is suppressed.  Here are two possibilities:

1. Define sine and cosine by:
   $$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \ldots$$
   $$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4} - \ldots$$
   It is not hard to show that the power series on the right-hand side converge on the entire real line, and thus they can be differentiated term-by-term to prove what you want.  The downside is that it takes a great deal of effort to show that the functions defined here have anything to do with the sine and cosine functions that you're used to; for example, try proving that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ or that sine and cosine have period $2 \pi$ this way.
2. By general theory from ODE's, the differential equation
   $$y'' + y = 0$$
   has a two dimensional solution space so define sine to be the unique solution $y_1$ satisfying the initial condition $y_1(0) = 0$ and $y_1'(0) = 1$, and define cosine to be the unique solution $y_2$ satisfying $y_2(0) = 1$ and $y_2'(0) = 0$.  Now set $y_3 = y_1'$.  Observe that $y_3(0) = y_1'(0) = 1$ and $y_3'(0) = y_1''(0) = -y_1(0) = 0$.  Moreover $y_3'' + y_3 = y_1''' + y_1' = (y_1'' + y_1)' = 0$, so $y_3$  solves the same differential equation as $y_2$ with the same initial data.  By uniqueness, $y_1' = y_3 = y_2$.

The downsides of this approach are (at least) twofold.  First, it is once again not easy to prove that the functions defined this way have anything in common with the usual sine and cosine functions (of course, if you know how to differentiate them already then you can use uniqueness).  Second, the proof of the existence and uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations is *much* harder than calculating the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: For anyone interested, a few years ago I wrote the details on how to start from the series definition and get the usual trigonometric functions (that is, the program outlined in 1) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2230792/22857).

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't like this, but here goes: $$\sin x={e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\over2i}$$ Differentiating, $$(\sin x)'={ie^{ix}+ie^{-ix}\over2i}={e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\over2}=\cos x$$

Comment: But yes I like it much! I think it's lot simpler/

Comment: It relies on knowing the derivative of $e^x$, which relates to the limit of $(e^h-1)/h$, which is not so different from the limit of $(\sin x)/x$. So in a way it's cheating. But I'm glad you like it!

Comment: Well..... So, Then is there any way to fully avoiding it? I'm in a discussion with somebody.

Comment: If you differentiate the Maclaurin series for sine, you get the Maclaurin series for cosine --- but that's also cheating, unless you have a way to get those series without first getting the derivative. Maybe someone else will come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

Some speculations.

Let $f(x)=(\sin x)', g(x)=(\cos x)'$.
Then $(\sin 2x)'=2f(2x)=2f(x)\cos x+2g(x)\sin x$.

$\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$ so $g(x)\cos x + f(x)\sin x =0$ and $g(x)=-f(x)\tan x$.

And finally we have $f(2x)\cos x=f(x)\cos 2x$. $f(x)=\cos x$ is obviously a solution.
Assuming $f(x)$ is continuous and periodic, may be it is possible to obtain that it is unique, I don't know.